# How to make a function act like a field in the Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with an IntegerField based upon a list of items.

```
LIST = (
    (0, 'None'),
    (1, 'Male'),
    (2, 'Female'),
)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=LIST, default=0)
    some_unimportant_value1 ...
    some_unimportant_value2 ...
```

There is also a function in the MyModel class which returns False if gender has not yet been assigned a value.

```
    def genderHasValue(self):
        if self.gender == 0:
            return False
```

When viewing the list of MyModels in the Django Admin area, I'd like to be able to see the computed result of the genderHasValue function. For example, the Django Admin area for MyModel might look like this:

```
some_unimportant_value1    some_unimportant_value2    genderHasValue
123                        456                        N
789                        012                        Y
```

This assumes the some_unimportant_value1 row has 0 as its IntegerField, and the some_unimportant_value2 row has 1 as its IntegerField.

Can the genderHasValue function be made do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be accomplished like this:

```
# admin.py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['some_unimportant_value1', 'some_unimportant_value1', 'genderHasValue']

    def genderHasValue(self, obj):
        if self.gender == 0:
            return False
        return True

# The file where you configure your admin
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

UPDATE:
To Answer your followup question in the comments: Yes it is possible, just put this:

`genderHasValue.short_description = "Gender Has Value"`

after your property definition

Comment: You don't even need to move the method to the admin class; you can reference model methods by name directly in list_display.

Comment: Thanks both for the replies. Question: is it possible to give the function a verbose name, so it has a nice heading value rather than "GENDERHASVALUE"?